# From ssas multidimensional cube, How to get top sales from factsales by salesPoint and month

Tags: ssas

I am using SSAS Multidimensional cube.I have factsales and two dimdate,dimsalespoint table. I need to show top sales every month by sales point.Also i need to show this data into power bi.My cube brower will be look like 
July salespoint1 1254
Aug Salespoint2  2589
Sep SalesPoint3  85236.
Per month which sales point sales high.
It will also filter year, product etc. 
Can any one help me.

Comment: This problem i have solved by cube.First create rank measure function by cube calculation.This rank measure field will be available into power bi measure.Add this rank field into filter by add data fields pane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do this with only PowerBI

You juste need to drag you sales infos and select max aggreagate and filter them by month and salespoint.

In powerBI you connect to your cube
[image]

you drag and drop your salesvalue and select the matrix visual
[image]

you use salespoint in row , date in column and salesvalue in values

[image]

You can select a max aggregate on your values
[image]

You'll get something like this :
[image]

and you can navigate in the date hierarchy by using the arrow on the top right

[image]

If you use a live connexion with an OLAP cube.
You can replace you max in powerBI by doing these step :

[image]

and select max [image]

you then have to use this measure in the powerBI report because it will be based on your table filtered by what you put in the visual(date, salespoint,...)

Comment: Thanks for your hard working support.Also your answer is correct from ssas import connection. But i have forgotten to mention, i am using ssas live connection for power bi. You can not modify measure and dimension into power bi for ssas live connection.

Comment: Ok then you juste have to create in your cube a measure like 
Max(SalesValues) and use this measure instead of  the salevalues transformed in powerBI.

Comment: MAX( [Dim Sales Point].[SalesPoint].[Sales Point Short Name], [Measures].[Sales Amount] ) this expression used in ssas md calculations. And Results looks like   Apr  Barisal 9163064
Apr B.Baria 9163064
Apr Bhyrob 9163064
May Barisal 8555468
May B.Baria 8555468
May Bhyrob 8555468
Jun Barisal 6808375
Jun B.Baria 6808375
Jun Bhyrob 6808375

Comment: I just adapt the end of my response for direct query is that what you expected ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response as well as hardworking. But i am using live connection instead of direct connection. That's why i am unable to create any new measure, unable to write any dax query. At all with ssas live connection you can't modify with power bi.

Comment: ho yes sorry i write direct query instead of live connection but the end of my response work with live connection on OLAP cube is that your configuration ?